# Transform string from associative array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'm storing images links into the database separating them with `,`, but I want to transform this string into an array, but I'm not sure how to do it.

So my array looks like this:

```
$array = array(
"name" => "Daniel",
"urls" => "http:/localhost/img/first.png,http://localhost/img/second.png"
);
```

So I'd like to have it in the following form:

```
$array2 = array(
"name" => "Daniel",
"urls" => array("http:/localhost/img/first.png",
                "http://localhost/img/second.png" )
);
```

Comment: fixing the db structure would be a better idea, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been PHP'ing for a while, but for that simple use-case I would use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$array['urls'] = explode(',', $array['urls']);
```

Uncertain if I interpreted your question correct though?

Comment: Explode will work for his case. Although he really should be storing multiple images in a second table linked by id of the first table. Storing anything in a single field by comma can lead to many issues later with flexibility and maintenance.

Comment: Agreed. But you gotta start with something.

Comment: If the urls contain comma(s), splitting by comma could be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk_recursive` like in the following example.

```
function url(&$v,$k)
{
    if($k=='urls') {
    $v = explode(",",$v);
    }
}
$array = array(
"name" => "Daniel",
"urls" => "http:/localhost/img/first.png,http://localhost/img/second.png"
);
array_walk_recursive($array,"url");
```

You can check the output on [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c5852eaee8697eafdfe21f718fcf3273da601c7)